# @tailwindcss/jit not working when configured in postcss.config.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

#### This is my dependencies and I already installed @tailwindcss/jit

[image]

## I Followed the Instruction given by the

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tailwindcss/jit

But when I try to replace  the **tailwindcss** object

```
 // postcss.config.js
  module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    }
  }
```

Inside the postcss.config.js
INTO THIS **@tailwindcss/jit** object

```
  // postcss.config.js
  module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      '@tailwindcss/jit': {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    }
  }
```

and when I try again to run using
yarn dev

**It got me this error**

```
error - ./src/styles/tailwind.css ((webpack)/css-loader/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!(webpack)/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-2!./src/styles/tailwind.css)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/media/acatzk/Hard%20Drive/backup/React-Projects/joshuagalit.com/src/styles/tailwind.css'
```

DOES IT EFFECT WHEN YOU TRY TO ADD jsconfig.json?
because i have this code and file structure

[image: tempo]

PLEASE HELP ME I NEED THIS KIND OF FILE STRUCTURE

**P.S**: I AM USING NEXT.JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in the version of Tailwind JIT you have installed (0.1.3). It's failing to compile because of the spaces in the file path.

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-jit/issues/22

A fix has already been released. All you need to do is update the dependency and it should be build as expected.

Comment: I took my files outside my bootable drive... and I think thats we're error happens...

Comment: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3791